# Why do my videos look like this?

Tags: 12.10, hd-video

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a and this only happens when I play some 1080p videos most 1080p videos and blu-ray disk work really well, but other do not. I have all the restricted extras installed so I'm not sure what the problem is. I've even tried on gnome mplayer, vlc, and dragon player.

[image]

Any help would be great.

Edit:
My Graphic card is 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller and the driver is driver=i915 latency=0 & my laptop model is a DELL Inspiron 17R-5720.

Comment: What graphic card do you have and what driver you have installed. If you don't the answer, just enter sudo lshw -c video to the terminal. Graphic card information is after "Product:" and driver name is after "configuration: driver=".

Comment: Ok. My Graphic card is ``3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller`` and the driver is  ``driver=i915 latency=0``.

Comment: Oh, is it laptop then? What model?

Comment: Yes. It's a laptop, it's a Dell inspiron.

Comment: My guess it is too little graphics memory, which is some part of your RAM, if you only have integrated graphics. so try to close as many programs as possible and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same thing happened.

Comment: Please also add the number after "Dell Inspiron". It can be that the full model name is on the bottom side, under the battery or something like that.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's a DELL Inspiron 17R-5720.

Comment: You should have Intel HD Graphics 4000 hardware that is currently using open source driver that came with Ubuntu. This should be more than enough to play 1080p video and that is why I suspect it is driver issue. Go to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads to download driver directly from Intel. Under Linux Graphics Installer choose either 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu version according to what you have installed. I know it says it is for 13.04 but let's hope it works also on your 12.10. Install the package and it should install the driver. Reboot and let us know how it went.

Comment: Yes!! That was it. Thank you very much! :3

Comment: Ok, let's now make all this easier to follow for people that might have a similar problem in the future. Edit your question by adding that your laptop model is “DELL Inspiron 17R-5720”. I will add an answer that you can accept as solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As your laptop model is “DELL Inspiron 17R-5720” it should have “Intel HD Graphics 4000” graphics adapter. This hardware should be more than enough to play 1080p videos and therefore problem is most likely with the driver (piece of software that makes it possible to use certain hardware).

From the output for `sudo lshw -c video` we can see that the driver installed for graphics is the open source driver (i915) that was installed automatically with Ubuntu. As you are experiencing problems with this driver you should try alternative one that you can get directly from Intel:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

“Under Linux Graphics Installer” choose either 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu version according to what version of Ubuntu you using. I know it says it is for 13.04 but let's hope it works also on your 12.10. Install the package and it should install the correct driver for your hardware. Hopefully it will fix your problem.

It is also worth to remind you that when installing drivers from other locations than official Ubuntu repositories it can introduce new problems to your system. But let's hope that this time everything will work out just fine.